# MIPS filling a variable size array

Tags: arrays, sorting, input, mips, user-input

For some reason the integer values i'm putting into memory of the array of base $t0 cant be accessed later on even though when debugging i can  clearly see that they are stored correctly in memory at 0($t0) and 4($t0) in the case of 2 integers. Its when i go into the passloop and attempt to load them into t6 or t7 that no value is being passed. Can someone explain why this is?

```
# bubble sort

.data
prompt1: .asciiz "Enter the array size \n"
prompt2: .asciiz "Enter integers to fill the array \n"
prompt3: .asciiz "Sorted Array: "

.text
    .globl  main
main:
la $a0, prompt1
li $v0, 4
syscall

li $v0, 5
syscall

add $t1, $zero, $v0
add $t2, $zero, $v0
sll $a0, $v0, 2
li $v0, 9
syscall
add $t0, $zero, $v0

loop:
la $a0, prompt2
li $v0, 4
syscall

li $v0, 5
syscall

beqz $t1, mainloop
sw $v0, ($t0)
addiu $t0, $t0, 4
subiu $t1, $t1, 1
bnez $t1, loop                                   


mainloop:
    subi    $a1,$t2,1              
    blez    $a1,done           


    li      $t3,0                   

    jal     passloop               


    beqz    $t3,done           

    subi    $t2,$t2,1               
    j       mainloop


#print sorted data, code still needed. Need to fix accessing issue first

done:
    j       end                     


passloop:
    lw      $t6,0($t0)              
    lw      $t7,4($t0)              
    bgt     $t6,$t7,swap       

next:
    addiu   $t0,$t0,4               
    subiu   $a1,$a1,1               
    bgtz    $a1,passloop           
    jr      $ra                     

swap:
    sw      $t6,4($t0)              
    sw      $t7,0($t0)              
    li      $t3,1                   
    j       next


end:
    li      $v0,10
    syscall
```

Comment: You should stop posting variations of the same question over and over again. What you _should_ do instead is learn how to use the debugging features in the simulator. For example, if you had set a breakpoint at `passloop` you would've easily seen that `$t0` is pointing past the end of your array.

Comment: i appreciate your help but i felt each question i asked held its own individual purpose but i can understand why you wouldnt see it that way. Im not familiar with what a "breakpoint" is or what that means. Im guessing the reason then why the values in the array t0 arent being carried over is because as you said t0 is pointing past my array but i have zero clue what that means in terms of fixing it. would i subtract by the amount of values in t0 then to get back to the 0(t0)?